# VBA Trying to retrieve a Path from Excel Range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to get links to Word documents from an Excel Range, but get a runtime error 13 at "doc.Documents.Open Path".

````
```
Sub wordsexcel()
    Set doc = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set doc = CreateObject("Word.Appliction")
    End If
    doc.Visible = True
    For Each Path In Range("Documents")
        doc.Documents.Open Path
        Set txt = doc.Words
        For Each word In Range("Words")
            If txt.InRange(word) Then txt.Select
        Next word
        doc.Save
        doc.Close
    Next Path
    Set doc = Nothing
End Sub

```
````

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? What is `doc`?

Comment: What variable type is `path`? What about `word`?

Comment: You need to declare your variables. If you already did, you need to then show them as part of the code - this is especially true for 'type mismatch' errors. `Dim Path As Range` would be an example.

Comment: I will give the code in full (I was discouraged to do so when creating this post :) )

Comment: What is stored in `Range("Documents")`?